# date_calc on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, package

I'm trying to install `date_calc` on Mac OS X (Snow Leopard), but I'm having some problems.

I've downloaded date_calc 5.4 and I've tried to do the following:

`sudo perl Makefile.PL`

I then tried:

`sudo make`

But this returns,

`make: *** No rule to make target`/System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/config.h', needed by `Makefile'.  Stop.`

Does anyone know what this means?

Thanks

Comment: You might need to be a bit more specific - there seems to be different packages called data_calc for PHP, Perl and perhaps others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could gather, it seems that this is an issue with Xcode not being installed, or being out of date.

Try (re)installing [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/index.php). Xcode 3 will probably be sufficient if you don't want to pay the few bucks for Xcode 4. The link is located in the bottom right of the page.

Comment: I'm installing Xcode 3.2.6 now and I'll let you know how it goes!